# Can we use Retrofit inside a loop in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, for-loop, retrofit, retrofit2

I know this kind of a weird question but I am trying to use my Retrofit call inside a for loop. What I am doing is sending my String[] elements one by one in the call with func like `insertdata(seperated2[0], seperated2[1], email, tag);`

But the loop are behaving weirdly when they are skipping the anonymous call for `call.enqueue(......onResponse(...) onfailure(.....))`

Instead of calling it with the loop control first finishes the loop and then comes to call.enqueue and always last element in loop. This is how loop looks like ....

```
 separated = currentString.split("\n");
for (int i=1; i<separated.length; i++) {
        seperated2 = separated[i].split(":");


        for (String aSeperated2 : seperated2) {
            Call<ServerResponse2> call = requestInterface.insertQrdata(seperated2[0], seperated2[1], email, tag);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse2>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse2> call, Response<ServerResponse2> response) {
                    ServerResponse2 serverResponse2 = response.body();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), serverResponse2 != null ? serverResponse2.getMessage() : null, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse2> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }

    }
```

here is an ex for seperated[] and seperated2[]

```
0 1
2 3
4 5
6 7
7 8
9 10
```

seperated[] is spliting them by line and seperated2 is spliting them by column.

> The Problem
>   When I check my seperated2[0] and seperated2[1] value for each iteration in on Response method it should be

```
sep2[0]= 0 sep2[1] = 1 
        2           3
and so on... for each iteration
```

but in each iteration the value in onResponse is always the last, i.e.

```
sep2[0] = 9  sep2[1] = 10
untill the length (say 6) same value at each iteration.
```

I don't know if am doing anything wrong but values are showing correctly when i use them outside of onResponse().

I know using retrofit like is not good practice but I was curious to how it will react in this situation. Can anyone help or give any suggestions ?

THANKS IN ADVANCE !!

Comment: Yes !! It's bad practice to make API calls such frequently. You can first prepare list of your strings/characters instead & make API call once which receives entire list just by one call.

Comment: Ya i know that and already did it but I was trying to this to check how it will react , so do you have any solution to this problem or any thought ?
@JeelVankhede

Comment: Take `seperated2` variable locally inside **main loop** *(initialize it inside main for loop)*, right now it's declared out side of main loop.

Comment: you mean inside the loop which is nested ??

Comment: I mean instead of `seperated2 = separated[i].split(":");`, try `String[] seperated2 = separated[i].split(":");`

Comment: ohh I did that globally , okay let me try this .... inside my for loop for i

Comment: if you want to call retrofit sequentially use it in a [synchronous](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests) mode

Comment: Better to chain requests with RxJava2

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of looping with retrofit library..if we use for loop the call.enqueue will not be called instantly for all iterations.so use this model.

```
private void UploadImagesTask(final String image, final int position) {
    ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    File file = new File(image);
    RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
    MultipartBody.Part photoArray = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("photo", file.getName(), reqFile);
    HashMap<String, RequestBody> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("token", Utils.createPartFromString(pref.getToken()));
    params.put("app_id", Utils.createPartFromString(pref.getAppId()));
    Call<ImageUploadResponse> imageUploadResponseCall = apiService.uploadImage(photoArray, params);
    imageUploadResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<ImageUploadResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ImageUploadResponse> call, @NonNull Response<ImageUploadResponse> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                urlList.add(Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getUrl());
                completeData.remove(position);
                completeData.add(position, getString(R.string.uploaded));
                uploadAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                pref.setTempData(Constants.IMAGE_UPLOADED, gson.toJson(urlList));
                if (position != uriData.size() - 1) {
                    int posi = position + 1;
                    CompressImages(posi);
                } else {
                    uploadDone.setActivated(true);
                    uploadDone.setEnabled(true);
                }
            } else {
                Utils.showSnackView(getString(R.string.error_occurred), snackView);
                uploadDone.setActivated(true);
                uploadDone.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ImageUploadResponse> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            Utils.showSnackView(getString(R.string.error_occurred), snackView);
            uploadDone.setActivated(true);
            uploadDone.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using for loop, you can use recursion too.
API will be called again and again but only after getting the response of the previous index.
In the onResponse() method you can call the method by incrementing the index value.
Because in for loop, the iteration will not wait for the completion of the execution of your API response, it will jump to the next iteration.

If you still want to use the loop then go for while loop

example for recursion:

```
    int i=1;
    separated = currentString.split("\n");

    void callMethod(){
seperated2 = separated[i].split(":");
 Call<ServerResponse2> call = requestInterface.insertQrdata(seperated2[0], seperated2[1], email, tag);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse2>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse2> call, Response<ServerResponse2> response) {
            ServerResponse2 serverResponse2 = response.body();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), serverResponse2 != null ? serverResponse2.getMessage() : null, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            i++;
            callMethod();
            }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse2> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

As per My suggestion do not use loops for this types of operation. Its bad idea If you can see performance wise.

You can do this things by following way:

> Retrofit is just call server URL and passing your data to the server.
>   So whatever process doing server side that you can change to do once only rather than doing everytime.

You can pass whole loop data in json format to the server once and do all looping  process in server side. It will be best for you.

Hope you clear my point of view.

Do let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: he is sending his data in chunks for some reason - did you notice that he already has the whole data, but he separates it (even twice!)?

Comment: Yeah, that is what I am trying to say. Do not separates, Send it as it is.

Comment: ok i will try another words: why he did such effort and separated his data when he could send the original huge data at once? he had to have a good reason for that...

Comment: Then he has to send `next call` of API once he get success response of `previous call` but do not have to call like that way.

Comment: he basically have to use [synchronous](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests) retrofit mode - thats all

Comment: hey guys.... i know i can send as it is in a junk even i did a similar effort but in this case i want to do it this way and want to observe the responses of my backend and retrofit ,,,

Comment: so i did something which is doin things fine ... i am getting the values as i want, for once forget about saving to backend lets talk about the API call part  ...... I am editing this ans and adding some info so guys can look on to it @PratikButani

Comment: and about the seperation part -- I have a multi line text like name: ghost \n age:25 ..... I have split that text firstly line wise i.e. separated[ ] and then acc to that separated , I have split the line part in separated2[ ] , EX: Seperated [1] = name  ghost  and 'separated2 [0] = name  separated2 [1] = ghost'  and sending them in Api call to create and dynamic columns at backend --- dynamic col. name = sep [0]  and its value dynamic col. value = sep [1]   .......

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you are yet never found the answer I have a suggestion for you. Divide the whole response into parts after that apply loop on that data and send data using Asynctask to server and create one interface so you can do anything on a response back.

```
            public interface GetResponse{
            
            public void onSuccess(ResponseModel model);
            
            publich void onFail();
            
            }
        
        In your async task
        
        public class AsyncTaskForApiSync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        GetResponse mcallback;
        
public AsyncTaskForApiSync(GetResponse mcallBack){
    
            this.mcallback=mcallBack;
        
          }
        
         @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        
        //retrofit api call in on success
    
        mcallback.onSuccess(response);
    
        }
    
        }
```

Sorry for my English. Also, let me know if you find any issue. Thanks.